# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in 264 WP Robot / empty page

Tags: php, wordpress

I hope someone can help me. I installed the affiliate store for wordpress here: http://kitapci.de/

When I click on "Kaufen" I get an empty page, so I enabled all errors.

Now I am getting this one: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /www/htdocs/w0117ba8/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 264

Code in this line

```
if ( false !== strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--noteaser-->' ) && ( ! $multipage || $page == 1 ) )
```

Any idea how I can solve it? Thank you!

Regards

Comment: The code on the Kaufen link is `window.open(''); return false;`, so opening a blank window is exactly what I'd expect it to do.  Perhaps you need to specify a link in the admin console.  I think you're better off asking on their support forums, since it's a commercial template.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I already asked them but no answer until yet :( 
There is for example this code: <a style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" onclick="window.open('<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "$tas_link", $single = true); ?>'); return false;">

So the script doesnt get tas_link? Thats why it is empty?

Comment: So the link's empty, either because it hasn't been set in the admin screen, or the `$tas_link` variable is incorrectly set.  Have you set a link for the product in the admin screen?

Comment: I don't think the `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` message has anything to do with your problem by the way.

Comment: `$post->post_content` is the only property in an object in that code. It says you are trying to get a property - that would be `post_content`, but that `$post` is not an object, hence "trying to get a property of a non-object". That means you need to go back to where you defined `$post` and check why it's not an object.